# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 761004032) (tried to allocate 755370216 bytes) in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\zip_extension.lib.php on line 55

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Am trying to import 120MB size database.zip file in `xampp` `PHPMyAdmin`.
I'm increse following in `php.ini`

`memory_limit=1200M`

`upload_max_filesize=1200M`

`post_max_size=1100M`

`max_input_time=5000`

But still i got `error`

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 761004032) (tried to allocate 755370216 bytes) in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\zip_extension.lib.php on line 55

How can i fix this ?

> Note: Original database.sql file size is `750MB`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
Open `cmd`

Type `cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin` and press enter.

After that type this following code:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < database.sql
```

> **Note:** Before this copy and paste your databse.sql file in `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`

Comment: Got this `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by following below steps:

1. Go MySQL bin folder as per your path i.e
   `E:\projects\mysql\bin`
   this is my computer path it may be different on your machine
2. Run the command to import command i.e `mysql -u root -p database_name < "E:/projects/htdocs/laravel/assets/database/database-140521.sql"`
   // make sure your path should be correct to the.sql file i.e
3. If it will show you screen something like below it means it starts and the database is importing you can check it your PHPMyAdmin

[image]

4. Once it will be complete it will show you screen something like this

[image]